# Why my class field is destroyed in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, attributes, destructor

In my constructor I initialize a field. The field is destroyed just after the initialization. 
Here's my  code and my test:

**A.hpp**

```
class A {
    private:
        T t;

    public:
    A(); 
    ~A();

    void add(string name, string num);
};
```

A.cpp

```
A::A() {
    cout << "Creating A\n";
    t = T(100);
    cout << "End\n";
}

void A::add(string name, string num) {
    cout << "calling add in A\n";
    t.add(name, num);
}
```

**T.hpp**

```
class T {
    private:
        E * t;
    public:
        T(int size=100);
        ~T();
    void add(std::string name, std::string num);
```

**T.cpp**

```
T::T(int size) : size(size) {
    t = new E[size];
}

T::~T() {
    cout << "Destroying\n";
    // delete[] t; // if I don't comment this I get Segfault when calling add method
}


void T::add(string name, string num){
        E e = E(name, num);
        t[0] = e;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A a;
    a.add("name", "num");
}
```

**Output**

```
Creating A
Destroying
End
calling add in A
Destroying
```

Comment: `// if I don't comment this I get Segfault when calling add method` - that's because you violate the Rule of Three / Rule of Five. Avoid manual memory management through raw `new` and `delete`. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: It's an exercise so I can't use vector

Comment: Then implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator correctly. Leaking memory is **not** a solution.

Comment: I took the liberty of  assuming the type `Agenda` mentioned in `main()` is really `A`. If not, feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
t = T(100);
```

is, equivalently:

```
T _temp(100);
t = _temp;
```

Which helps visualize why some `T` is getting destroyed. It's not your `t`, it's the temporary `T(100)`. That's why you see two prints of "Destroying"... one for the temporary, and one for `A::t`.

To avoid the spurious destruction, use an initializer list:

```
A::A() 
: t(100)
{ }
```

Comment: You might want to put a pair of braces around the "equivalent" formulation to really stress the point of immediate destruction of the temporary.